# Can I add together the values of the cells in each Matrix row?

Tags: matrix, math

The Matrix docs say:

> :average, :lowest, :highest, and :sum
>
> These tags return the average, lowest, highest, or sum value of a given numeric column in your Matrix field.

I have a matrix field that is all about hours spent on different activities and different weeks. I not only want to get the sum of each column (the weeks) but also the sum of each row (the activities) and if possible get the sum of every cell in the whole table. Is that possible or do with just Matrix or do I need to install something like the Simple Math Add-on?

so instead of {matrix_field:sum col='week1'} is there something like {matrix_field:sum row_id="1"}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this using Matrix and the [Math add-on](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/math) - but not in Matrix without any other add-ons/PHP.  I hope that helps!

Comment: Not the answer I wanted, but the answer I expected. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with php on output, how about

```
<?php
$my_row_sum = {matrix_field:sum col='week1'} + {matrix_field:sum col='week2'} + etc...;
?>
```

Comment: Yeah, great idea! ... but I need PHP on input. :(